# Is it correct to say "a cut on / in my skin", and "a cut on / in my arm"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, phrase-request

According to my research, it seems that people say "*there is a cut **in** the paper/ in the dress*" and "*there is a cut **on** my arm/ **on** my leg*".

I wonder why people say "**a cut in the dress**" but "**a cut on my arm**".

I guess we use "**in**" for thin layers such as cloth, paper, material and "**on**" for thick solid substance such as a piece of wood.

But I might get it wrong.

So I guess we say "**there is a cut in my skin**" but "**there is a cut on my arm**", but I am not sure.

Comment: You've got it! It's worth noting that with each type of damage (cut, scratch, dent, tear, ...) and different materials, the correct preposition can change.

Answer (score 1):

One factor is whether it goes all the way through. A cut "in" a piece of a paper usually means that the cut goes all the way through and makes a hole in the paper. A cut "on" your arm usually means that there is an indentation on your arm, but it doesn't go all the way through.

Answer (score 1):

- *cut **on** my arm* vs. *cut **in** my arm*: This is a specific sense of "cut" meaning a long thin skin wound. My sense is that **on** is the default or zoomed-out view which explains where on my body the cut can be found, and emphasizes that the cut is visible on the surface of the skin. **In** is the zoomed-in view which focuses on the opening created by slicing down into the skin.
- *There is a cut in the paper/dress*: Out of context this sounds a bit odd. If a blade (knife or scissors) was applied to the paper/dress, it is not wrong exactly, but it might be more natural to say that there is a *hole* or a *slit* in the paper/dress. If no blade was involved it might be better described as a *tear* in the paper/dress. **In** is better if there is a full separation of (part of) the material. **On** works if the cut is an indentation in the surface (e.g. a cut on a piece of wood).